# Solving in positive integers an equation containing exponentials 

Tags: nt.number-theory

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/solving-in-positive-integers-an-equation-containing-exponentials) on [Math.SE](http://www.math.stackexchange.com) and it has been a while that no non-trivial hint has been suggested. I hope MOers will have something to say or will solve it entirely. Here is the question copied verbatim:

I stumbled upon this number theory problem while I was solving another problem. Here is the equation: $$3^kn + 3^{k-1} + 2^m(3^{k-1} + 2h) = 2^{m+l}n$$ where $k \geq 3, h,l,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n$ is odd, not a multiple of $3$ and $n\geq 7$. My impression is that it does not have a solution. However, I have not progressed on the problem anymore than that. Could you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: The equation implies $3n\equiv2^m-1\pmod{2^{m+1}}$, but that's about the only nontrivial restriction (given $n,m,k$ satisfying this congruence, you can complete it to a solution (I think)). For example, $m=2$, $n=1$, $k=3$, $h=7$, $l=5$ solves the equation.

Comment: Collatz strikes again.  Gerhard "Hates Wool Over His Eyes" Paseman, 2011.03.17

Comment: @Emil, thanks for your comment. That's interesting but I want nontrivial solution for $n\geq 6$. I will include it in the question.

Comment: @Gerhard, could you please tell me why you said that?

Comment: Chulumba, please read Emil's comment again. $n=7, m=1, k=3, h=2, l=4$.

Comment: @Chulumba: That does not make any difference. As I said, take any $n,m$ such that $3n\equiv2^m-1\pmod{2^{m+1}}$ (such an $n<2^{m+1}$ exists for every $m$, and adding an arbitrary multiple of $2^{m+1}$ to $n$ will retain the congruence), and any $k,l$, then $h:=(2^{m+l}-(3^kn+3^{k-1}+2^m3^{k-1})/2^{m+1}$ is an integer, solves the equation, and if $l$ is sufficiently large, is positive. For example, take $n=9$ and $h=108$, and the rest as before.

Comment: Correction: there's a bracket missing in $(2^{m+l}-(3^kn+3^{k-1}+2^m3^{k-1}))/2^{m+1}$.

Comment: If you take $n$ such that $3n+1=2^m$, your equation simplifies to $3^{k-1}+h=2^{l-1} n$, which has plenty of solutions because you just set $h$ to be what you want. By the way, your equation doesn't look very natural, so it would be good if you could give us some more motivation.

Comment: First, M. Brunault said it better than I did, for which I apologize.  Second, it looks similar to equations arising from various attempts at solving the syracuse, or Collatz, problem.  If you have different motivations, it would be good to hear them.  In spite of my offhanded remark, it may prove fruitful (or a waste of time) to compare your experience with those attempting to solve the Collatz problem.  I hope you respond to Brunault's implicit request.
Gerhard "Removing Both Feet From Mouth" Paseman, 2011.03.17

Comment: @Emil, thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: @Gerhard. Dear Gerhard, you were absolutely correct. The equation arose out of trying to formulate cycles in the Collatz in terms of an equation. What's more, upon googling, I found the pdf: "The3n+1 Collatz Problem and Functional Equations" which was along the lines as you suspected mine. But I refrained from commenting until the question phased out of the first page; otherwise, people are going to consider me a crank trying to solve the 3n+1.  Thanks very much for your comment. I wish you do not mind my lateness. 

Comment: @François Brunault, your suggestion was very convincing as the equation was not something natural. For reasons I gave for G. Paseman above, I opted not to give motivation for otherwise the moderators would close my question and my future questions would not be given due attention( if I get the crackpot label). (This was also my reason for not commenting till the question came behind the first page.) Thanks very much. Good day.

Comment: Chulumba, I appreciate your candor.  For the future, my suggested abbreviation of your question is: "While working on Collatz, I came across the following.  I have not found it in the literature.  Can someone tell me if this has been considered? Also, is it clear whether it has any solutions at all?"  This (with more detail) is more open, and indicates what work you have done.  An honest reference-request would be closed only if it seemed obvious that you had not done enough looking.  Others might give you a good reference as an answer.  Gerhard "Honesty Is A Good Policy" Paseman, 2011.03.21

Comment: Also, even though I was right about the source, I should not be so quick to attribute motive.  I apologize to Chulumba for any slight, insult, or harm I may have caused with my "wool over eyes" remark. Gerhard "Humility Is Not Bad Either" Paseman, 2011.03.21